# How to select the first inner array?

Tags: ruby, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have the following:

```
arr = [["1/31/2012 8:00 PM"]]
```

Right now, to get that string I end up doing `arr.first.first`...which just seems awkward.

What's a more direct way to get `1/31/2012 8:00 PM`?

Comment: Seems fine to me.  What is indirect about that?

Comment: Just seemed janky, but if there's no `first.first` shortcut, then so be it. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on your array purpose, you have several options:

1. `arr[0][0]` is is equal to `arr.first.first`. But I think `arr.first.first` is normal solution
2. `arr.flatten.first`
3. Consider other structure for `arr` with which you will be able to query for this data more naturally like `meeting.nearest # => "1/31/2012 8:00 PM"`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems the correct way to do it, but, you can also do

```
arr.to_s
=> "1/31/2012 8:00 PM"
```

But be cautious. This will concatenate the elements in the array into a single string, if more than one element is present in the array

```
[["this", "is"]].to_s
=> "thisis"

[["this", "is"], ["test"]].to_s
=> "thisistest"
```